# How to mark parts of an Image (Image manipulation) with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to build a Web application where people can mark part of an Image and change different parts of the image (according to the items already available in the shop) Like the video link below.

I need suggestion on Javascript/HTML/any Technology on how to Mark object(wall in case of my application) in an image.

I googled but only found full featured image editor or some random js that i don't need. like this,

- http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php
- http://maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap/
- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukpf19pv/2/)

```js
var O = {
  doc: document,
  body: document.body,
  wd: window,
  ce: function(a, b) {
    return a.appendChild((a = O.doc.createElement(b))), a;
  },
  cc: function() {
    var c, g, gn;
    c = O.ce(O.body, "canvas");
    c.width = O.w;
    c.height = O.h;
    g = c.getContext("2d");
    gn = {
      sfc: function(a) {
        // Set fill color
        g.fillStyle = a;
      },
      slc: function(a) {
        // Set line color
        g.strokeStyle = a;
      },
      slw: function(a) {
        // Set line width
        g.lineWidth = a;
      },
      bp: function() {
        // Begin path
        g.beginPath();
      },
      mt: function(a, b) {
        // Move to
        g.moveTo(gn.tp(0, a), gn.tp(1, b));
      },
      t: {
        // Transform
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        sx: 1,
        sy: 1
      },
      tp: function(a, b) {
        // Tranform point
        return O.mfl(a ? b * gn.t.sy + gn.t.y : b * gn.t.sx + gn.t.x) + 0.5;
      },
      tps: function(a, b) {
        // Tranform distance between points
        return O.mfl(a ? b * gn.t.sy : b * gn.t.sx);
      },
      lt: function(a, b) {
        // Line to
        g.lineTo(gn.tp(0, a), gn.tp(1, b));
      },
      cp: function() {
        // Close path
        g.closePath();
      },
      fill: function() {
        g.fill();
      },
      line: function() {
        g.stroke();
      },
      arc: function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        g.arc(gn.tp(0, a), gn.tp(1, b), c, d, e, f);
      },
      rc: function(a, b, c, d) {
        // Rectangle
        g.rect(
          gn.tp(0, a) - 0.5,
          gn.tp(1, b) - 0.5,
          gn.tps(0, c),
          gn.tps(1, d)
        );
      },
      frc: function(a, b, c, d) {
        // Fill rectangle
        g.fillRect(
          gn.tp(0, a) - 0.5,
          gn.tp(1, b) - 0.5,
          gn.tps(0, c),
          gn.tps(1, d)
        );
      },
      st: function(a, b, c, d) {
        gn.t.x = a;
        gn.t.y = b;
        gn.t.sx = c;
        gn.t.sy = d;
        gn.slw(1 / O.min(c, d));
      },
      cls: function() {
        gn.sfc(O.cols.white);
        gn.slc(O.cols.black);
        gn.frc(0, 0, O.w, O.h);
      }
    };
    gn.cls();
    return gn;
  },
  init: function() {
    O.body.style.margin = "0px";
    O.body.style.padding = "0px";
    O.cols = {
      red: O.rgb(1, 0, 0),
      green: O.rgb(0, 1, 0),
      blue: O.rgb(0, 0, 1),
      white: O.rgb(1, 1, 1),
      black: O.rgb(0, 0, 0),
      yellow: O.rgb(1, 1, 0),
      lightBlue: O.rgb(0, 1, 1),
      purple: O.rgb(1, 0, 1),
      gray: O.rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    };
    O.w = O.wd.innerWidth;
    O.h = O.wd.innerHeight;
    O.wh = O.w / 2;
    O.hh = O.h / 2;
    O.pih = O.pi / 2;
    O.pi2 = O.pi * 2;
    main(O);
  },
  rf: function(b, c) {
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    a.open("get", b, true);
    a.onreadystatechange = function() {
      a.readyState != 4 || (a.status && a.status != 200) || c(a.responseText);
    };
    a.send();
  },
  ca: function(a, b) {
    return (Array(a) + "").split(",").map(b);
  },
  pad: function(a, b, c) {
    return (a += "").length >= b ? a : Array(b - a.length + 1).join(c) + a;
  },
  rgb: function(a, b, c) {
    return "#" + O.rgbf(a) + O.rgbf(b) + O.rgbf(c);
  },
  rgbf: function(a) {
    return O.pad(O.mro(a * 255).toString(16), 2, "0");
  },
  cols: null,
  ael: function(a, b) {
    O.wd.addEventListener(a, b);
  },
  rel: function(a, b) {
    O.wd.removeEventListener(a, b);
  },
  w: null,
  h: null,
  raf: function(a) {
    // Request animation frame
    O.wd.requestAnimationFrame(a);
  },
  rand: function(a) {
    // Random integer
    return O.mfl(O.mra * a);
  },
  randf: function(a) {
    // Random float
    return O.mra() * a;
  },
  rq: function(a, b) {
    // Require
    O.rf("/" + a + "/1.js", function(a) {
      eval(a);
      b();
    });
  },
  wh: null,
  hh: null,
  pi: Math.PI,
  pih: null,
  pi2: null,
  mfl: function(a) {
    // Math floor
    return Math.floor(a);
  },
  mra: function() {
    // Math random
    return Math.random();
  },
  mro: function(a) {
    // Math round
    return Math.round(a);
  },
  mce: function(a) {
    // Math ceil
    return Math.ceil(a);
  },
  max: function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  },
  min: function(a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b);
  }
};
O.init();

function main(O) {
  var gridX = 32;
  var gridY = 32;

  var coords, pressed, cx, cy, g;

  (function() {
    g = O.cc();
    coords = [];
    pressed = 0;
    O.ael("keydown", onKeyDown);
    O.ael("mousedown", onMouseDown);
    O.ael("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    O.ael("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  })();

  function onKeyDown(a) {
    switch (a.keyCode) {
      case 13:
        switch (+prompt("0 - Clear\n1 - Get JSON\n2 - Paste JSON")) {
          case 0:
            coords.length = 0;
            g.cls();
            break;
          case 1:
            prompt("", JSON.stringify(coords));
            break;
          case 2:
            coords = JSON.parse(prompt("Pase JSON:"));
            drawCoords();
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  function onMouseDown(a) {
    if (!a.button) {
      cx = snapToGrid(0, a.clientX);
      cy = snapToGrid(1, a.clientY);
      pressed = 1;
    }
  }

  function onMouseMove(a) {
    var x, y;
    if (pressed) {
      x = snapToGrid(0, a.clientX);
      y = snapToGrid(1, a.clientY);
      if (x != cx) {
        g.bp();
        g.mt(cx, cy);
        g.lt(x, cy);
        g.line();
        cx = x;
        coords.push(cx, cy);
      }
      if (y != cy) {
        g.bp();
        g.mt(cx, cy);
        g.lt(cx, y);
        g.line();
        cy = y;
        coords.push(cx, cy);
      }
    }
  }

  function onMouseUp(a) {
    if (!a.button) {
      pressed = 0;
      coords.push(null);
    }
  }

  function snapToGrid(a, b) {
    return a ? O.mro(b / gridY) * gridY : O.mro(b / gridX) * gridX;
  }

  function drawCoords() {
    var a = coords.slice(),
      q;
    g.cls();
    g.bp();
    g.mt(a.shift(), a.shift());
    while (a.length) {
      if ((q = a.shift()) == null) {
        g.mt(a.shift(), a.shift());
      } else {
        g.lt(q, a.shift());
      }
    }
    g.line();
  }
}
```

And so, I saw Canvas. Do I need to learn canvas? I have not done this kind of work before, so considering this any kind of suggestion would be appreciate.

I need to mark the image like this link here. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTXuP_EJx74

Comment: if you want to manipulate images in javascript, then, yes, you probably want to learn `<canvas>`

Comment: Thank you. And any other suggestion about marking image would be greatly appreciated.